# Swap JSON key and value

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON object that I'm trying to swap the keys with their value. The values are all unique but the keys are not. Because they are not unique, when creating an object the non unique keys are removed.

Is there anyway I can invert the keys and values before creating an object? I was attempting to do this with underscore but this library only allows you to invert object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
   <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var myObj = {
                "503": "07:25",
                 "507": "06:00",
                 "500x": "06:50",
                 "500x": "07:20",
                 "500": "07:35",
                 "503": "07:50",
                 "507": "07:40",
                 "500x": "07:55",
                 "500": "08:30",
                 "500x": "08:00",
                 "500": "10:45",
                 "507": "09:05",
                 "500": "10:45",
                 "507": "09:05",
                 "500": "13:45",
                 "500": "16:45",
                 "500": "20:00",
                 "500": "22:00",
                 "500N\n*Thur/Fri Only": "23:00"
       },

       myObj = _.invert(myObj),
       keys = Object.keys(myObj),
       values = Object.values(myObj),
       i, len = values.length;
       console.log("Total len = " + len) 
       values.sort();

       console.log(myObj);

     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       k = keys[i];
       v = values[i];
       console.log(k + ': ' + v);
     }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you getting myObj ? if myObj  is already created then data is lost

Comment: I have a file that contains all the JSON in this format : https://pastebin.com/Ppv7in9t

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not valid JSON. Keys are required to be unique in JSON.

Comment: @vasekhlav You're right it's invalid in its current form. If the key/values were swapped it would validate correctly. May have to look into using something outside of javascript to swap the values

Comment: You also have some duplicate property values within a given object, so drawing board.

Comment: Your current objects should probably be arrays of small objects with known property names, like `[{"code": "503", "time": "07:25"}, {"code": "507", "time": "06:00"},...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could convert your obj to string, then using regex you can get the words between `""` and then use for loop to group them together.

**NOTE:** You need to escape `\n` inside string.

```js
const myObj = '{"503": "07:25","507": "06:00","500x": "06:50","500x": "07:20","500": "07:35","503": "07:50","507": "07:40","500x": "07:55","500": "08:30","500x": "08:00","500": "10:45","507": "09:05","500": "10:45","507": "09:05","500": "13:45","500": "16:45","500": "20:00","500": "22:00", "500N\\n*Thur/Fri Only" : "23:00"}';
       
var result = myObj.match(/"(.*?)"/gm).reduce((res,word)=>{
  res.push(word.replace(/"/g,''));
  return res;
},[]);

var swapped = {};
for(let i = 0 ; i < result.length - 1; i += 2){
  swapped[result[i + 1]] =result[i]
}

console.log(swapped);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This works perfectly for my situation. I've marked this as the correct answer it appears it cannot be solved with javascript as the data is already an object which is removing non unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
var myObj = {
 "503": "07:25",
 "507": "06:00",
 "500x": "06:50",
 "500x": "07:20",
 "500": "07:35",
 "503": "07:50",
 "507": "07:40",
 "500x": "07:55",
 "500": "08:30",
 "500x": "08:00",
 "500": "10:45",
 "507": "09:05",
 "500": "10:45",
 "507": "09:05",
 "500": "13:45",
 "500": "16:45",
 "500": "20:00",
 "500": "22:00",
 "500N\n*Thur/Fri Only": "23:00"
};

function swap(json){
var ret = {};
for(var key in json){
ret[json[key]] = key;
}
return ret;
}

console.log(myObj);
console.log(swap(myObj));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This removes the non-unique keys when declaring the myObj variable.